# how can get all phone number from a string

Tags: android, string

Here is my string, i add to my TextView in my android app:

```
mString = "hsfjsdhfjsdv ij,qfdbsxbsddsvsd 76897879 fdsgsfg 67676545, 34343465";
```

How can get all phone numbers from a specific string so i can add onclick to those phone strings and call them.

Any idea how can i do that?

Comment: How do you know something is a phone number and not just a list of digits?

Comment: use a pattern matching